# Before Exiting execute code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to set column onoffline to "off" right before exiting the aspx webpage.

I tried putting in Page_Unload and in two places in Global.aspx.vb: Session_End and Application_End but none of them put an "off" in the "onoffline" column.

```
    ' To Fire when the session ends
    Dim connStr, cmdStr As String
    Try
        connStr = "connection string works"
        cmdStr = "UPDATE [sessionregister] SET [onoffline]=@onoffline;"
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@onoffline", "off")
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()
                cmd.Dispose()
                conn.Dispose()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Does this code execute? If so, does it show an error?

Comment: Can you debug the session_end method? If you add a System.Diagnotic.Debug.Writeline .... before and after the update, you can see the writes on debugview?

Comment: how about executing this code while logging out of the application?